# Calculating the Norm of an operator in $L^2(0,1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

If I have the following operator for $H=L^2(0,1)$:

$$Tf(s)=\int_0^1 (5s^2t^2+2)(f(t))dt$$ and I wish to calculate $||T||$, how do I go about doing this:

I know that in $L^2(0,1)$ we have that relation:

$$||T||\leq \left ( \int_0^1\int_0^1 |(5s^2t^2+2)|^2dtds\right ) ^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{50}{6}}.$$
Thanks for any help

This is incorrect as pointed out in the comments below

Can I just take $f=1$ so that $||f||_2=1$ and $||Tf(s)||=\left (\int_0^1 \int_0^1 |(5s^2t^2+2)|^2\right )^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{50}{6}}$

So this gives that $||T||=\sqrt{\frac{50}{6}}$?

Comment: Could you explain how did you get $T(1)(s) = \Big(\int_0^1 \big( \int_0^1(5s^2t^2+2)\ dt \big)^2\ dt \Big)^{1/2} = \Big(\int_0^1 \int_0^1 |5s^2t^2+2|^2\ dt\ ds\Big)^{1/2}$?

Comment: @user67133 via a mistake, thanks- so that is not how I do the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an answer but may be of some help to find the solution. Here your $T$ is the Hilbert-Schimdt integral operator with $$K(s,t) = 5s^2t^2 +2 $$ Now operator norms of these over $L^2$ are not very easy to find, I know the result is $ 2/\pi $ when $ K(s,t) = \chi_{\{ s\geq t\}} $ i.e. when $ Tf(s) = \int^s_0 f(t) dt $. But a strategy may be followed where you have to find $ T^*$, then use the identity $ \|T\| = \sqrt{\|T^* T\| } $ and $ T^*T $ being self-adjoint and compact (you have to check compactness) you have $ \|T^*T\| $ as the spectral radius of $T^*T$. So you need to find the eigenvalues. So take an eigenfunction $f$ and eigenvalue $\lambda $ of $T^*T$ and use the relation
$$ T^*T(f)(s) = \lambda f(s) $$ You will probably end up in a second order ODE. Then try to find the eigenvalues and then its maximum.